# initializing template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++03, c++98

I'm not an expert in templates and caught up in writing some code, where I've to initialize some template parameter and i'm getting some issues,

I'v e a structure like

```
template <typename T>
struct SomeData
 {
    int m_x;
    int m_y;
    // a bunch of primitive members
   Buffer<T> my_buffer; // mainly it is Buffer(float) but I'll prefer using     T

    SomeData(int x=0;int y=0): m_x(x), m_y(y), my_buffer(???)
    // copy constructor??
    // destructor,??

}
```

// buffer is a smart pointer implementation using templates and it basically containts some members like

```
template <typename T>
class Buffer
{
  { some Nested class NN
   }
  // NN mem_1;
  // NN mem_2;
  // T* buffer;
  // some operator implementations , including =, [], (), +, -, * etc
  // constructors ,destructors
}

}
```

Now i'm stuck in my SomeData implementation, like what exactly shall be my copy construcotr, constructor and operator = looks like here? and what is more efficient for performance like shall i go for template specialization here? since T shall be a float always. 
AND IT HAS TO BE OLD C++ (98/03) not the newer one. Thanks

Comment: Start with replacing `buffer` in the initializer list to `my_buffer`.

Comment: Oh yes right, that shall be something close to my_buffer(mem_1, mem2,buffer) will update the code

Comment: I would suggest solving the problem first without using templates. Once you figure that out, it will easier to solve it using templates.

Comment: Problem is already solved, attempting to replace a raw pointer (float* bufferptr) with this smart pointer class, issue is using templates 'properly' like using my_buffer(NULL,NULL,NULL)  in initialization list or how to write a proper copy constructor in templated world